# Raspberry pi 3 Node-RED Error:npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/pi/package.json'

Tags: node-red

how are you?
I have a problem. Please help me?
I used Node-Red on raspberry pi 3. I setup python function but i dont setup. :)
I use this code on terminal windows.

npm install node-red-contrib-python-function

and i take this error lines:

- npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/pi/package.json'
- npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/pi/package.json'
- npm WARN pi No description
- npm WARN pi No repository field.
- npm WARN pi No README data
- npm WARN pi No license field.
- - node-red-contrib-python-function@0.0.2
- updated 1 package in 4.51s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of those are errors - they are warnings that you don't have a package.json file in place. But the install of the module has succeeded.

However, you should have run it in the directory `/home/pi/.node-red` in order for Node-RED to find the module. Alternatively, you could have used the palette manager from within the Node-RED editor itself to install the module.

Comment: Thanx a lot my dear friend. I am add to palette manager and added pythonshell node. But deploy gave an error. Error message is: Flows stopped due to missing node types. Pythonshell in.